# Disabling CSS validation in Aptana Studio 3

Tags: eclipse, aptana

Anyone know how to disable CSS validation with Aptana Studio 3? In version 3.0.4 the warnings remain even after completely [disabling the W3C CSS Validator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6652793/how-can-i-suppress-certain-css-errors-in-aptana-studio-3).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you tried to manually delete all existing warnings? Disabling the validator will not create any new warnings, but the existing warnings remain.

Right click on the warnings and click *Delete*.

Answer (score 4):

This is a known issue with Studio 3.0.4: http://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-3371.

A workaround is to do a Project > Clean on the selected project, or you could update to the nightly build using the instruction at http://aptana.com/r/apupdate.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the issue. Clean didn't work, but I may try switching to nightly.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problem is still there. If I switch the CSS validator off and clean the project, the errors disappear. On the other hand, if I turn on and add some regular expressions in order to exclude some errors, the validator still shows the "excluded" errors, even with after executing a "clean project" command. It look likes that the regular expressions are somehow omitted.

BTW, I'm working with the version Aptana Studio 3, build: 3.1.1.201204131931