# Disabling CSS Validation in Aptana Studio

Tags: aptana3

I'm using Aptana Studio 3.0.9, and it is currently marking a number of errors on CSS files.

I have tried the procedure [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6652793/how-can-i-suppress-certain-css-errors-in-aptana-studio-3), including filtering by .* (which should filter every CSS error), but the errors persist.  I have cleaned, restarted, and they will not go away.

The method [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7323107/disabling-css-validation-in-aptana-studio-3) is not an option, as right-clicking on the errors does not give an option to delete.

The files in question are

- boostrap.css
- chosen.css

both of which are actively developed, well-tested files.  The problem is that because Aptana marks them as having errors, the entire project is marked.  This is both annoying and dangerous, as I am less attuned to errors I actually might make while developing.

How can I get rid of the errors?  I'm okay with just hiding them in the project explorer.  I'm okay with getting rid of all CSS validation (I'm not using much of my own CSS in any case).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm on Aptana 3.0.9 for Linux. So hopefully it is the same on whatever OS you're using. But I figure it should be the pretty close.

This solution will turn off the errors completely for css

Basically similar to the first link you posted.

Go to Window -> Preferences -> Aptana Studio -> Validation

Now on this tab, if CSS is not selected, select it.

There should be a part for Validators. W3C Styleshet Validator should be checked. If you uncheck it, the css validation goes away and you don't get errors any more.

Comment: Aargh!  I did this, but had to go to each offending file and switch the two validators on and off before the errors finally disappeared.  Thanks.