# Ignoring CSS Expressions in Eclipse/Aptana

Tags: css, regex, eclipse, aptana, css-expressions

I'm working on some old CSS which has some hacks, specifically CSS expressions, built in for various versions of IE. Thanks to these hacks I get a mountain of CSS syntax errors and I'm trying to ignore them.

In the CSS Syntax Validator I've tried adding the following filters to try and ignore them:

```
.*expression\(.*
.*expression.*
.*[expression\(]{1}.*
```

And none of them have worked.

**Does anyone know how to make Aptana Studio ignore CSS expressions?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6652793/how-can-i-suppress-certain-css-errors-in-aptana-studio-3 , but according to the answer there and the documentation, at least your second pattern should work.

Comment: That's what I thought. After digging around for a few hours, it seems it has to do with a faulty CSS validator which isn't being properly updated anymore. Switching to Eclipse made it work perfectly.

Comment: @Mike C - if you've found the answer, you should post as an answer and accept the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that Aptana's CSS validator isn't being properly updated and there's a bug in reading the filters. The only true solution I found was to change over to Eclipse.